# Why is Object.create() used in this case in prototypical inheritance?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Consider this code :-

```
function Rectangle(length, width) { 
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}

Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function() {
    return this.length * this.width;
};

function Square(size) { 
    Rectangle.call(this, size, size);
}

Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);

var rect = new Rectangle(5, 5);
var square = new Square(7);

console.log(rect.getArea());   // 25
console.log(square.getArea()); // 49
```

Why do we have to do the inheritance like this :-

```
Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);
```

And not like this :-

```
Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype;
```

They both seem to do the required task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype` means that they're both **the same object**, which is almost certainly not what you want. A Square is a Rectangle, but a Rectangle is not a Square, so the behaviors will not be the same. You need two distinct prototype objects.

Using `Object.create()` is a clean way to create an object that has a given object (in this case, `Rectangle.protoype`) as the head of its prototype chain. The result is that `Square.prototype` is a distinct object, and can be given its own properties (special methods applicable to a square but not a rectangle), but it will also have access to methods from the Rectangle prototype.

So when you create a Square via `new Square(100)`, you get an object whose direct prototype is the object created with `Object.create()` and (presumably) decorated with all sorts of interesting Square behaviors. *That* object, in turn, has `Rectangle.prototype` as the first thing in its prototype chain. The effect of that is that if you call, say, `mysquare.area()`, and `area()` is defined on the Rectangle prototype, the lookup will proceed from the Square instance, to the Square prototype, and then to the Rectangle prototype where the method will be found.

Comment: @TJCrowder has an excellent writeup somewhere about why using `Object.create()` is a much better idea than using `new`.

Comment: Got it, this was really helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Object.create adds another object on top of the target prototype.  This means you can set properties on this object without modifying the original prototype